# Badge cheating?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, badges

I came across a user with low rep but a gold famous question badge and was curious. It seems his question (the only one he has) was marked as a duplicate of *the* actual famous question.

This seems to be some kind of loophole.

Steps (this is by no means an encouragement to do the same):

1. find a famous question
2. make a new question asking essentially the same thing
3. get your question marked as a duplicate of the famous question
4. get a nice shiny gold badge

Is this intentional?

Besides good ethics/morals, whats stopping anyone from doing this exact same thing to get *undeserved* badges?

---

Edit: This is not as severe as I thought. The question in question actually does have enough views to be a famous question though it may be entirely due to the fact that it was marked as a duplicate to a famous and well rated question. By chance or not, I suppose this sort of this is most likely frowned upon but not reversed.

Comment: Don't view it as a flaw, view it as an enhancement ^^ (Evil laugh). BTW Do the user that creates the duplicate have to wait for the views to start accumulating or does it give the badge automatically.

Comment: PLease at least link to the question!

Comment: @JorgeCastro: Didn't want to point the finger. I will flag it though.

Comment: It's not a big deal, the big win is finding high traffic duplicates and duping them properly.

Comment: Ironically, perhaps, is that you were one of the ones who marked it as a dupe.

Comment: Yeah the autoforwarding is a newish feature, there are still tons of older questions like that though, flag em as you find them.

Comment: Who cares about badges?

Comment: People who don't have a nice set of them perhaps.

Comment: Hmm, what's wrong with _this_ question to deserve so many downvotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a question is a duplicate it automatically gets forwarded to the master question, I don't think this increases the view count; unless there are answers posted, in which case you can flag to either have those removed, or (if they're good) flag and ask for a merge so all the traffic is going to the master question.

If the person is getting a bunch of views then it's an indication that the question either has a search term or something that the master question does not, so they should be merged/duped for the sake of the user's finding the canonical question.

I don't think anyone does this intentionally, the onus is on the community to keep the duplicate chain maintained, and if using a badge to find these works then do so. We should be using the famous question badges to see which questions need to be maintained anyway.